# adb DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR and INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, apk, adb

Im trying to install an apk, i had it installed but i uninstalled it, rebooted my device, but now on the phone, i have "Update this app?", which is confusing, i uninstalled it, app manager and adb list doesnt show it, adb install shows this: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE and adb uninstall shows this: DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR, ive seen some other posts but they were talking about uninstalling the app/the system trying to remove a system app.

How could i solve this issue? only thing i have in mind is somehow force uninstalling it.

i tried other posts, tried them, but they didn't work

I also tried using adb install -r (apk file), but it didn''t work

I want it to install, as normally.

SOLVED:
Install the version you just uninstalled, uninstall it with the data using settings/adb, then install the new version.

Comment: SOLVED: Install the version you just uninstalled, uninstall it with the data using settings/adb, then install the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Install the version you just uninstalled, uninstall it with the data using settings/adb, then install the new version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).